# A cold mentioned the second time

Tags: articles

There is this fixed phrase - to catch a cold. I wonder if I'm mentioning the same cold one more time, should I say "The / this / that cold" or just "cold"?

> I caught **a cold** when I was walking around the town in the rain;
> now I am lying with fever under the blanket, suffering from **the
> cold** and taking medicine for cough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, you could use any of those three words in that place.

You cannot use just 'cold' without one of the three, however, since that makes it sound like you are suffering from low temperature cold instead of the health condition.